# Upload to a stuck Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino

Due to some poor coding I have accidentally uploaded a script that has the same effect as this:

```
#include "Keyboard.h"

void setup() {
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  Keyboard.print("hello world");
}
```

I accidentally called a broken function in `void loop` that I didn't check fully and now I can't clear it as it won't stop printing characters to the screen.

So far I have tried pushing reset while uploading and holding reset while uploading, and neither worked. I even tried uploading via ICSP and all I got was red text saying can't communicate with board.

I have an Arduino Uno that is working that can be used if required to fix the Leonardo.

I don't have enough coding ability to solve this on my own. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed too clear the Arduino in the end by just luck. There is a few milliseconds on startup, where the board is on, but no code is running. If you are lucky enough that your programmer begins its upload then, assuming your code is short, it can overwrite the faulty code.

```
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```